# "ls" in a container within a volume shared with Windows host gets stuck when there are many files in a directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-desktop, volumes

## Background

I am running a Spring Boot application in a docker container (Ubuntu image).
The code is written in Kotlin and it walks through a directory on disk that contains 300,000 files.
I run the following code:

```
  File(dir)
    .walk()
    .forEach{logger.info("{}", it.name)}
```

and this code blocks for at least 10 minutes.

I would expect that lines should start being printed very shortly after invoking walk.
Indeed the code works as expected when running it from Intellij - that is, not in a container.

## Question:

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

---

### What I Have Tried

### First Trial

I have tried just calling File.listfiles and logging the number of files like so:

```
   val count = File(dir).listFiles().size
   logger.info("{}", count)
```

This also blocked for a very long time and eventually logged the value 0.

### Second Trial

I changed the settings for Docker Desktop.
I increased the RAM to 20 GB and the swap file to to 1 GB
This had no effect on the result.

Comment: Are the files part of the image or are they part of a volume?

Comment: The are part of a volume

Comment: If you are on Mac, maybe [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/) can help you improve the performance of volume mounts.

Comment: Thanks. I am running Docker for Desktop on my Windows development machined and will be running on RedHat for production. Are you suggesting that there is a voulme size limit even for volumes that are mapped to directories on the host?

Comment: No, actually it's the difference of file systems in host and container: _on macOS (and other non-Linux platforms) there are significant overheads to guaranteeing perfect consistency, since messages describing file system actions must be passed synchronously between container and host._ This kind of problem is new to me (I'm using Linux), so I'll let you know if I find something for Windows optimizations.

Comment: Do you think that the problem is the size of the data in the volume or the number of files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209485/discussion-between-david-sackstein-and-stefan-golubovic).

Answer (score 1):

Following [Stefan Golubovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4778343/stefan-golubovi%C4%87)'s comments I realize that this question is probably unrelated to kotlin or java and more likely to be related to the implementation of volumes in Docker for Desktop.

Therefore I submitted a more focused question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677656/listing-the-contents-of-a-directory-in-a-shared-volume-with-200k-files-from-with) and I will close this one.