# Listing the contents of a directory in a shared volume with 200K files from within a ubuntu container hosted in windows gets stuck

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-volume

## Problem

Listing the contents of a directory in a shared volume with 200K files from within a ubuntu container hosted in windows gets stuck.

## How to reproduce

1. Install Docker Desktop 2.2.0.3 (42716) stable on Windows 10
2. Configure docker to work in WSL (Ubuntu 16 distribution)

   - Expose daemon on `tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS`
   - In WSL, define environment variable `DOCKER_HOST=localhost:2375`
   - In WSL, in `/etc/wsl.conf` in the `[automount]` section, define `root = /`
3. Create a folder on the Windows host that contains 200,000 files (even small ones). e.g. `c:/temp`
4. Run a docker container, mapping c:/temp on the host to /opt in the container as follows:
   `docker run -it -v /c/temp:/opt ubuntu bash`
5. In the bash prompt of the container run `cd /opt` and then `ls`

## Expected Result

The `ls` command will start to list all files in the c:/temp folder.
This can be expected to take some time, but it will begin almost immediately.

## Actual Result

Nothing is printed and the shell does not respond.
Moreover, CTR C does not interrupt the `ls` command.
The only way I found to stop the container is to restart Docker Desktop

Comment: FYI -- `ls`, by default, does sorting; so it needs to get the whole list back before it can start printing anything at all. `find . -maxdepth 1`, by contrast, will print things as fast as they're returned by the OS. Mind you, depending on the remoting layer in use between Docker and your host, that might still be slow (conceivably, something in that tooling could add a requirement for a full-directory iteration that `find` otherwise doesn't have); but it'll be closer to the actual performance at which content is retrieved.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. "." was printed immediately and then the shell stuck as before.

Comment: That tells us something useful about the behavior -- the delay happens before the first name is returned to the guest kernel. Also, it generally implies that the protocol is pretty heavyweight -- not just directly proxying through syscalls, in which case it could return immediately, but requesting the full list.

Comment: I posted a New Issue for this on the Docker for Windows repo: 
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6020